# What does "|=" operator means in C#?

Tags: c#

Just walked through [referencesource.microsoft.com (line 217)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/gc.cs)

and discovered "|=" operator. What does it means? I assume it some sort of Boolean operation- but can't get what exactly it means. Does it mean "or equal", short form like  "a= a|b"  ?

Comment: Do you know about `+=`? As in `a += b`. Same thing.

Comment: You can check that by reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|=` is to `=` what `+=` is to `=`. Just a shortcut to avoid the writing of `a = a | b`

Answer (score 2):

its a bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator.

For details refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. This operator is known as the "OR assignment" operator and a |= b is equivalent to a = a | b. Here is the 
[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx).